# \hhline with || separation in coloured table

Tags: tables, color, colortbl, hhline

I want to create a table like the following. Using `booktabs` is unfortunately
not an option. I need to colour the table header and want to show on which
columns the `\multicolumn`s are used. Therefore I use `\hhline` with `||` to
introduce a small break in the lines. But the space between the two lines is
white and not coloured.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{ccccc}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray}\multicolumn{3}{c}{Foo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bar}\\
  \hhline{---||--}
  \rowcolor{gray}foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  \hline
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution doesn't have to use `hhline` but should look just like `\cline`.

Comment: you can colour the lines and the spaces between using hhline as redefined by colortbl, see the richard of york example in the colortbl doc

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain what you want with a supplementary empty column and using the possibility for an \hhline to have segments with different colours. Here is a code, in which I took the liberty to replace  the gray colour by a lighter shade of grey, making  the contents of the coloured cells more readable:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[]{ccc!{\hspace*{-2pt}}c!{\hspace*{-2pt}}cc}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke}\multicolumn{3}{c}{Foo}& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bar}\\%
\hhline{--->{\arrayrulecolor{WhiteSmoke}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}--}
  \rowcolor{WhiteSmoke}foo & bar & baz & & bang & bang \\
  \hline
  foo & bar & baz & & bang & bang\\
  foo & bar & baz & & bang & bang\\
  foo & bar & baz & & bang & bang\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The empty column is an option I'd like to avoid, but gives good results. I personally am satisfied by my own solution though. Nonetheless you get an upvote :) And the changed colour is no problem -- as you can see in my own answer, I didn't use a dark grey as well, it was just to minimize the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a better (imho) looking solution than the `\hhline` approach
which inserts the correct color in the space between the `\cline`s. The
definition of `\@mycline` matches the one of `\@cline` just with the additional
`\rule`s added.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}

\definecolor{tablegray}{gray}{0.85}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myclineColor[1]{\colorlet{mycline@color}{#1}}
\myclineColor{tablegray}
\newcommand*\mycline[1]{\@mycline#1\@nil}
\def\@mycline#1-#2\@nil
  {%
    \omit
    \@multicnt#1%
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne
      \@firstofone{&\omit}%
    \fi
    \@multicnt#2%
    \advance\@multicnt -#1%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    {\color{mycline@color}\rule{0.5\tabcolsep}\arrayrulewidth}% inserted
    {\CT@arc@\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill}%
    {\color{mycline@color}\rule{0.5\tabcolsep}\arrayrulewidth}% inserted
    \cr\noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{ccccc}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{tablegray}\multicolumn{3}{c}{Foo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bar}\\
  \mycline{1-3}\mycline{4-5}\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}
  \rowcolor{tablegray}foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  \hline
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which provides tools to color tabulars in a way compatible with the rules of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!40}{1,2}
\Body
  \toprule
  \Block{1-3}{Foo} &&& \Block{1-2}{Bar} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang \\
  \midrule
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang \\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang \\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang \\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang \\
  foo & bar & baz & bang & bang \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]